# How to download <p> tags with JSoup and display them in a textview in android?

Tags: java, android

Okay so I'm using JSoup to extract the `<p>` tags I'm interested in from this particular web page every time a button is pressed, and I was wondering how I could put one of these `<p>` tags into a textview each time the button gets pressed. Right now, the all of the `<p>` tags are being downloaded each time the button gets pressed, which I don't want. Anyone know what to do?

Here's what my code looks like:

```
private class Text extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String title;
        String textviewDisplay;
        Elements li;
        int numTimesOfRefresh = 0;
        Document document;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Basic JSoup Tutorial");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                if(numTimesOfRefresh == 0){
                    document = Jsoup.connect(url1).get();
                } else if (numTimesOfRefresh > 1){
                    document = Jsoup.connect(url2).get();
                }
                // Get the html document title
                title = document.title();
                Elements div = document.select("div.facttext");
                Elements p = document.select("div.facttext > p");
                for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
                    Log.d("jsoup", " " + p.get(i));
                    System.out.println(p.get(i));
                } 
                //Log.d("jsoup", "size: " + li.size());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set title into TextView
            TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textview.setText(title);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            numTimesOfRefresh++;
            System.out.println(numTimesOfRefresh);

        }

    }
```

My layout looks something like this: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-HsLChD8_E7U/T8_bR9L8OpI/AAAAAAAAA-g/n2ed0KIblfA/s1600/buttondemo2.png

Comment: Which `<p>` tag do you want? The first on the page? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I want to download 10 <p> tags from the page, but I only want one of those to be displayed in a textview everytime the button is pressed .@user184994

Comment: But which one out of those 10? The first one? Or a different one each time you press the button?

Answer (score 0):

Get the tags, as you've already done:

```
Elements p = document.select("div.facttext > p");
```

Then, just select which one you want:

```
// get the first
textView.setText(p.first());

// get a random one
Random rand = new Random();
textView.setText(p.get(rand.nextInt(p.size()));
```

Comment: Wow, that's awesome I didn't think about doing it that way! Now, how do I increment this, so that the next time the user presses the refresh button, it gets the second one? And if they press it again, to get the third?